# Chartjs v4 Chart Title and Legends not showing

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

I have created a pie chart as follow

```
import React from 'react';
import { Pie } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import {Chart, ArcElement, Title, Legend} from 'chart.js'
Chart.register(ArcElement);

const GenderRatio = () => {
  const data = {
    labels: ['Male', 'Female'],
    datasets: [
      {
        data: [60, 40], // Replace with your actual male and female ratio values
        backgroundColor: ['#8F91C0', '#FF94C2'], // Set colors for each segment
        hoverBackgroundColor: ['#36A2EB', '#FF6384'], // Set colors for hover effect
      },
    ],
  };

  const config = {
    type: 'pie',
    data: data,
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      plugins: {
        legend: {
          position: 'top',
          display: true
        },
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'Chart.js Pie Chart'
        }
      }
    },
  };

  return <Pie data={data} options={config} />;
};

export default GenderRatio;
```

However the titles and legends are not displaying on the screen.

Im currently in chartjs @4.4.0 and react-chartjs-2@5.2.0.

I saw some of the posts stating that the title and legend should not be in the plugins namespace, but it wasn't working for me either way.

Comment: You forgot to `register` `Title` and `Legend`. Add those two in the call to `Chart.register` to enable legend and title. The configuration seems OK.